# SSRS indicators - how do I read them in Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I ported an older Crystal report which showed values by having an X or a blank in a column to SSRS, and decided to replace the X/blank with a Indicator control, showing a checkmark. Looked lovely, but when my boss exported it to Excel, we discovered that he could no longer count the marked cells.

I have a partial workaround involving two rows, one with indicators and one with just the 0/1 values behind the indicators, and choosing which one to show with the RenderFormat global, but I *really* don't like duplicate rows like that. Is there a better way to do this, either on the SSRS or Excel side of things? Thanks.